# How to .addClass to duplicate or same classes being created dynamically

Tags: jquery

I want to **highlight** table rows having same class which generated by the database (so i don't know exactly what class will appear)

**Here's the HTML Markup looks like**

[image]

**So far i tried this:-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
        var txt = $(this).find("td:last").text();
        txt = parseInt(txt);
        if (txt = txt) {
            $(this).addClass("alert alert-danger");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I believe the class names can start with number `https://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/`. However I am not sure what is expected output in your case. Also did you notice your `if` block, instead of comparing you are assigning variables.

Comment: If there are multiple groups of classes how do you decide which group to highlight and with what color. And If highlighting in your case means adding the classes `alert alert-danger` then wont all the highlighted groups look just the same? This is so ambiguous. Does this highlighting occur on some event like `mouse hover` or is it just changing the background color of rows when the table is rendered.

Comment: `alert alert-danger` will make the rows background color red. And yes, i want them red, even if the groups are different. And this should happen without any event.

Comment: check update section of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using assignment operator instead of comparison operator

change this

```
if (txt = txt)
```

to this

```
if (txt == txt)
```

Also what you are currently doing will always fall in true condition

```
   var txt = $(this).find("td:last").text();
       txt = parseInt(txt);
```

since you get the text and parse itself to `number` value. Then matching with the same `txt` value. This will always going to be `true`

**Update**

You can group the rows on the basis of class name as below, However you can change the color as per your convenience.

```js
  
   $('tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
      var rowClass= $(this).attr('class');
      var back = ["#ff0000","blue","gray"];
      var rand = back[Math.floor(Math.random() * back.length)];
      if(rowClass.length>0){
         $('tr.'+rowClass).css('background-color',rand)
       }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr class="">
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
 <tr class="">
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
 <tr class="7998">
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
 <tr class="7998"><td>Hello</td></tr>
 <tr class="7998"><td>7998</td></tr>
 <tr class="8142"><td>Hello</td></tr>
 <tr class=""><td>Hello</td></tr>
 <tr class=""><td>Hello</td></tr>
 <tr class="7730"><td>Hello</td></tr>
 <tr class="7730"><td>Hello</td></tr>
 <tr class="7730"><td>7730</td></tr>
 <tr class="7730"><td>Hello</td></tr>
 <tr class="7957"><td>7957</td></tr>
 <tr class=""><td>Hello</td></tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked in the fiddle. But i dont have values in the `td` only class names on `tr` how to do this without comparing with `td` just compare `tr` classes?

Answer (score 1):

Do you looking something like this?

This example will highlight any row that have a more than 1 same name in table.

And if it single/none, it won't highlight it.

HTML

```
<table class="list">
   <tr class="8008"><td>8008</td></tr>
   <tr class="8002"><td>8002</td></tr>
   <tr class="8008"><td>8008</td></tr>
   <tr class="8088"><td>8088</td></tr>
   <tr class=""><td></td></tr>
   <tr class="8077"><td>8077</td></tr>
   <tr class="8077"><td>8077</td></tr>
</table>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = [];
$(".list tr").each(function(){
        arr1.push($(this).attr("class"));
});
console.log(arr1.length);
$(".list tr").each(function(index){
        var newArray = arr1.slice();
    newArray.splice(index, 1); // remove index value from an array, so this index != match its own
            console.log(newArray);
    if ($.inArray($(this).attr("class"), newArray ) !== -1)
            $(this).addClass("alert");

});
```

And the JSFiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/synz/6284poux/